# How did the Ancient Greeks forge and shape metal gears?

Tags: ancient-greece, greek, astronomy, metallurgy, computers

The closest to answer I've gotten is this video:
[Wikipedia: Making gears by hand without machines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxzWk7v9sUo)

However, I don't really know if Archimedes and his contemporaries would have the above tools or not. I'd assume his process would be more rudimentary and less refined. More specifically, I'm wondering how the complex set of gears in the Antikythera were made.

Comment: Isn't sand casting actually quite easy with bronze? Or casting with the other mold materials they used for the bronze statues.

Comment: Wouldn't they need the gears to be accurate and smooth for the antikythera? Perhaps I'm wrong in that assumption.I'm pretty sure die casting is far better for producing small, accurate gears.

Comment: However, could Archimedes have done something as energy intensive as forcing molten metal at high pressure into a mold cavity (i.e. die casting)? Just pouring liquid metal into a sand cast would be too inaccurate, wouldn't it?

Comment: If they needed to be very accurate, they could use clay/plaster casting instead of sand casting or the "lost wax" method they used with statues. And after the piece was produced, hammering, sanding and polishing would make it perfect. Ancient Greeks did very detailed bronze decorations for helmets and little statues with these methods

Comment: you may have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZioPDnFPNsHnyxfygxA0to4RXv4_jDU2

Comment: Did Archimedes "forge and shape metal gears"?

Comment: @kimchilover Perhaps not, but somebody had to have and I'm just wondering how they did it.

Comment: @DanM Thank you so much! That's such a helpful series of videos!

Comment: It's worth remembering that while they certain made gears, they didn't make a lot of them -- things like the antikythera machine were hardly in mass production! So they almost certainly used the same techniques they used for making jewelry.